# Need help about Mining and Difficulty levels!

Tags: mining-profitability

I am new to these mining things and i want to know that, "What if the difficulty level increase?, would i make a loss with mining? I am mining $1 USD with 5MH/s server with the current difficulty."

Can someone shed some light on this matter? I will be very thankful to him

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining#Difficulty

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, as the difficulty goes up, and you keep the same hardware, your earnings will go down. If they drop below the cost of mining (including electricity, etc), then yes, you will have a loss.